# SQL Server to Oracle10g conversion

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle

I currently have a SQL Server (Express 2005) database to hold some transaction/metadata that I now want to migrate to Oracle 10g express instance.

Can you do this programmatically or is there a decent software tool that anyone can recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle Migration Workbench is [included in SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/migration//workbench/index_sqldev_omwb.html). Check it out to see if it meets your needs.